# Simultaneously Diagonalizing Bilinear Forms

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

> Let $\theta$ and $\psi$ be symmetric bilinear forms on a
>   finite-dimensional real vector space $V$, and assume $\theta$ is positive
>   definite. Show that there exists a basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ for $V$
>   and $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
>   $$\theta(v_i,v_j)=\delta_{i,j}\quad\text{and}\quad\psi(v_i,v_j)=\delta_{ij}\lambda_i$$
>   where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta function.

I think it's enough to choose a basis $\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$ for which the matrix representations of $\theta$ and $\psi$ are both diagonal. Then $\left\{\frac{w_1}{\sqrt{\theta(w_1,w_1)}},\ldots,\frac{w_n}{\sqrt{\theta(w_n,w_n)}}\right\}$ is the required basis.

Answer (score 6):

Your question essentially reduces the to [spectral theorem for symmetric bilinear forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem). Use $\theta$, the positive definite form, as an inner-product. This makes $(V,\theta)$ a (real) inner product space, and hence spectral theorem applied to $\psi$ will give you an answer.

---

For a sketch of the proof of the spectral theorem, what we can do is to look at the set of all vectors $S := \{ v\in V| \theta(v,v) = 1\}$. Note that by positive definiteness every vector $w\in V$ can be written as a multiple of some $s\in S$. In fact, $S$ is a topological sphere and is compact. So we can let $e_1$ be a vector in $S$ such that $\psi(e_1,e_1) = \inf_S \psi(s,s)$. Let $S_1 = S \cap \{e_1\}^\perp$ where $\perp$ is defined relative to $\theta$. We can define $e_2$ as a vector in $S_1$ such that $\psi(e_2,e_2) = \inf_{S_1} \psi(s,s)$ and so on. By induction we will have arrived at a collection of vectors which are orthonormal with respect to $\theta$. That they are also $\psi$-orthogonal follows by minimization: if there exists $s\in S_1$ such that $\psi(e_1,s) \neq 0$, we have that for $a^2 + b^2 = 1$
$$ \psi(a e_1 + b s, a e_1 + b s) = a^2 \psi(e_1,e_1) + b^2 \psi(s,s) + 2ab \psi(e_1,s) = \psi(e_1,e_1) + b^2 (\psi(s,s) - \psi(e_1,e_1) + 2ab \psi(e_1,s)$$
By choosing $|b| < 1/2$ sufficiently small such that
$$ \left|\frac{1}{b}\right| > \left|\frac{\psi(s,s) - \psi(e_1,e_1)}{\psi(e_1,s)}\right| $$
and with the appropriate sign, we see we can make
$$ \psi(a e_1 + bs, a e_1 + bs) < \psi(e_1,e_1) $$ 
contradicting the minimisation assumption. By induction the same can be said of all $e_i$, and hence they are mutually orthogonal relative to $\psi$.

---

It is important to note that the assumption that $\theta$ is positive definite is *essential*. In the proof above we used the fact that for a positive definite form, its corresponding "unit sphere" is a topological sphere and is a compact set in $V$. For an indefinite form or a degenerate form, the corresponding "sphere" would be non-compact (imagine some sort of hyperboloid or cylinder), and hence it can happen that the infimum of a continuous function on the surface is not achieved, breaking the argument.

In fact, given two symmetric bilinear forms *without* the assumption that at least one of them is positive definite, it is possible that they cannot be simultaneously diagonalised. An example: let 
$$ \theta = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix} \qquad \psi = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$
Suppose you want $(x,y)$ and $(z,w)$ to simultaneously diagonalise the matrices. This requires in particular
$$ xz = wy \qquad xz - wy - xw - zy = 0 $$
for the cross terms to vanish. Hence we have
$$ xw + zy = 0 $$
Assuming $x \neq 0$ (at least one of $x,y$ is non zero), we solve by substitution $z = wy / x$ which implies $w(x^2 + y^2) = 0$. Since $x^2 + y^2 \neq 0$ if $(x,y)$ is not the zero vector, this means $w = 0$. But the equation $xz = wy = 0$ implies that $xz = 0$. By assumption this implies $z = 0$ and hence $(z,w)$ is the zero vector, which contradicts our assumption.

A similar proof can be used to show that
$$ \theta = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \qquad \psi = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
also cannot be simultaneously diagonalised.

Answer (score 3):

The catch is finding a basis which simultaneously diagonalizes $\theta$ and $\psi$.

Take $V = \mathbb{R}^n$ for simplicity, and let $\theta (x,y) = \langle x, A y \rangle$, and $\psi (x,y) = \langle x, B y \rangle$, with $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. By assumption $A=A^T >0$, and $B= B^T$.

Since $A>0$, it has a Cholesky decomposition $A = Q^T Q$ (with Q invertible, of course). Now consider the matrix $Q^{-T} B Q^{-1}$. Since this is symmetric, it can be diagonalized by an orthogonal $U$ to give $U^T Q^{-T} B Q^{-1} U = \Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is diagonal. Also notice that $U^T Q^{-T} A Q^{-1} U = I$ (since $Q^{-T} A Q^{-1} = I$).

Now choose a basis $v_i = Q^{-1} U e_i$, where $e_i$ is the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then we have
$$ \theta(v_i, v_j) = \langle Q^{-1} U e_i , A Q^{-1} U e_j \rangle = \langle e_i , U^T Q^{-T} A Q^{-1} U e_j \rangle = \langle e_i , e_j \rangle, $$
and similarly
$$ \psi(v_i, v_j) = \langle Q^{-1} U e_i , B Q^{-1} U e_j \rangle = \langle e_i , U^T Q^{-T} B Q^{-1} U e_j \rangle = \langle e_i , \Lambda e_j \rangle, $$
from which the desired result follows.